# How to go from Try to Catch in specific condition in Try

Tags: c#

I have a specific condition in try want it to be in catch if happened

```
string x;
try {
    if(x==null)
        //send to catch
}
catch {
    //Show messagebox
}
```

I tried throw new Exception but found most of answers here recommend not to use and i have more than 1 condition i want to send each separated to handle in different catch
so is this possible or I should just spam if else ?

what I realy trying to do is that

I have 2 TextBox want to make sure they not empty and 2 DateTime Picker want to make sure 1always before the other (start date and end date)

Comment: It's recommened not to use a throw/catch situation to control standard logic (i.e. non-faulting logic) because the call stack will be analyzed to produce the caught exception and is much slower. As mayu said, you probably just need an if statement, and not a try catch. What is the specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you want it to be in catch? Why not just replace `//send to catch` with `//Show messagebox`?

Comment: I have 2 TextBox want to make sure they not empty and 2 DateTime Picker want to make sure 1always before the other (start date and end date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Point to be noted,** throwing exceptions in your code slows down the performance of your application. So always avoid throwing non-fatal exceptions. Throw exceptions only when you cannot handle the consequences.

For everything else that you should handle using either `if` or `switch` (if you need to test multiple cases).

*Example:*

```
string x;
if(x == null) { /* show message */ }
if(x == "") { /* show another message */ }
if(x == "1") { /* show yet another message */ }
```

Using switch:

```
string x = null;
switch (x)
{
    case null:
    Console.WriteLine("string is null");
    break;
    case "":
    Console.WriteLine("string is empty");
    break;
    case "1":
    Console.WriteLine("string is 1");
    break;
}
```

By the way for string is null or empty, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Answer (score 2):

you can use throwing an exception into try to go straight to catch.

see below code: `SOME_System_Exception` can be any system exceptions

```
string x;
try {
    if(x==null)
        throw new SOME_System_Exception();
}
catch {
    //Show messagebox
}
```

Comment: Some note about this being a really bad design would be appropriate. :)

Comment: eeewww - as they say

Answer (score 0):

I think `if` is all you need.

```
if(x==null) {
    //do what you need to do
} else if (x.Value < 3) {
    //do something else 
} (...)
```